# List not displayed when application returned back to AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

When I call `ProcessTask` the first time when app runs it successfully displays data in `ListView` but when the app runs again(after pressing back button and opening APP once again) and calling the `ProcessTask` again, then I am mot able to view the data in the`ListView`....why?

here is the code

```
private class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask <Integer, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground( Integer... arg0 ) {
        try {
            mReader.power( slotNum, Reader.CARD_WARM_RESET );
            mReader.setProtocol( 0, Reader.PROTOCOL_T0 );
            publishProgress(  );
            createRootNode();
            prepareListData();
            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter( MainActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild );
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        expListView.setAdapter( listAdapter ); //this displays the data
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not compile. please fix it.

Comment: Thank you dear Anurag for your invitation to the chat room. I asked some question there. I really appreciate if help me. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/74478

Comment: @TheGoodUser Your query is answered in above chat

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the @Override like below, but the problem I think is that in the second time, you already set an adapter, so you have to tell to refresh the data, and you do it with notifyDataSetChanged().

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    expListView.setAdapter( listAdapter ); //this displays the data
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: "Try to delete the @Override", no don't do that. That's the opposite of what should happen.

Comment: Tried this but still it displays for the first time but not for the second time :(

Comment: But when i move this
expListView.setAdapter( listAdapter ); //this displays the data
to a button click then everything works fine...why?

Answer (score 0):

first know if the result is false or not, if it's false do nothing, otherwise setadapter and notify data changed in adapter.

try using this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != false) 
            expListView.setAdapter( listAdapter ); //this displays the data
    }
```

and in background worker change:

`listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter( MainActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild );` to:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter( MainActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild );
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried this but still it displays for the first time but not for the second time :(

Comment: can you please post your whole code here?
you can also add me on Facebook for private conversation: fb.com/Awais.is.King
or WhatsApp: +920363355690